# GPU sharing criterion for VNC solution

Tags: graphics-card, vnc, gpu, xforwarding

For my job, I need to know if Virtual Network Computing solution (VNC), for doing export display, is sharing GPU ressources on server side where there is a GPU graphics card on this side.

Actually, we are searching for another solution, in addition to our existing solution (TurboVNC/VirtualGL) and one of our criteria is to be able to allow different client users to share graphics ressources of one GPU card on one node, i.e to be able to open multiple sessions on server side.

for the moment, TurboVNC/VirtuaGL allows to do this sharing and as TurboVNC is a "modified" VNC solution, I wanted to know if this is the case for VNC.

Thanks

Comment: I would just compare the sources but thats not a solution everyone can do.  Is this a listed feature for either software.  have you simply tried it, should be easy enough to verify, it either words or it doesn't.

Comment: yes, I do a study software of the existing solutions for doing remote visualization (x forwarding) and I try to see if this criterion is respected for each solution. I only test TurboVNC/VirtualGL (the only solution that we have for the moment). Anyone would not have a feedback concerning this GPU sharing for VNC ?